# Predicting new data with classifier

Tags: python, machine-learning

Hi I have a program where I am trying to train different models to choose the most accurate one. Therefore I have:

```
def updateBestClassifier(predictions, classifier, name, count_vect):
   global bestAccuracy, bestClassifier, modelName, bestCountVect
   if(predictions > bestAccuracy):
      bestAccuracy = predictions
      bestClassifier = classifier
      modelName = name
      bestCountVect = count_vect
```

where `bestAccuracy` is initially 0 and predictions is the accuracy score of a model. I update `bestClassifie`r with the actual model, the model name (a String) and `bestCountVect` with the `count_vect`.

Then I try to predict new text with the following lines:

```
text = unknownDf['Text']
transText =  bestCountVect.transform(text)
predict = bestClassifier.predict(transText )
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Incompatible dimension for X and Y matrices: X.shape[1] == 17400 while Y.shape[1] == 5000
```

Any idea why please?

Comment: Could you provide the code of your fitting process ? It's hard to help with such few infos

Comment: `X` and `Y` are nowhere shown in the code you have shared; nevertheless, it is apparent that they don't have the same length (each sample must correspond to a label, and vice-versa). May be you are mixing your training and validation/test sets?